# How to cast MySQL "NOT IN" array to integer

Tags: mysql, grafana

I am trying to use an options field in Grafana. Once I enable "ALL", the array switches to strings and this will mix up the chart.

This is the query where I get the custom variables from:

```
SELECT
  m.id AS  __value,
  m.name AS __text 
...
```

This is the generated pannel query:

```
WHERE
   ID in ( 2 )
```

Once I enable the option "all", grafana will switch for the same variable selection to:

```
WHERE
   ID in ( '2' )
```

Resulting in mixed up time stamps.

Is there another way to work around this with MySQL and use an alternative to `ID in` query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Grafana advance variable formatting](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/variables/advanced-variable-format-options/), e.g. csv:

```
WHERE
   ID in ( ${idvariable:csv} )
```